# InvalidCastException in Mono when trying to GetValue() on an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, mono

I'm in the process of creating a Binding solution within Mono that enables developers to have two-way binding. All property types work except `IEnumerable`, in that for some reason Mono throws an `InvalidCastException` whenever I event attempt to try and use `PropertyInfo.GetValue()` for it.

Even though the `PropertyInfo` shows all signs that the `Collection<>` / `IEnumerable<>` is finding its type correctly (ie if I debug, it shows that the property being passed in derives a Collection...but just can't extract the actual value?

Here's the code:

```
var src = Source.GetType().GetProperty("Foo");
if (typeof (IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(SourceProperty.PropertyType))
{
    var obj = src.GetValue(Source, null);
}
```

The error I get:

> InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
>
> System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetterAdapterFrame[VMController,Array] (System.Reflection.Getter`2 getter, System.Object obj) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoProperty.cs:234)
> System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object[] index) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoProperty.cs:292)

Comment: It seems to me that MvvmCross already implements such a binding solution, https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/4.0/MvvmCross/Core/Binding You might check how it gets through similar challenges.

Comment: With such an incomplete code example, it's not entirely clear where the problem might lie. But given you're storing the `PropertyInfo` for the property in `src`, why is your `if` condition not referencing `src.PropertyType` instead of `SourceProperty.PropertyType`? What _is_ `SourceProperty`? Why do you believe that to be valid to use there? That still wouldn't explain the exception (`GetValue()` returns `object`, so assuming the property exists, it shouldn't matter what type you think it is; the call should still succeed. Without more details, you're not likely to get an answer.